# Any kernel monitor alternatives?

Tags: parallelization, kernel

Sometimes the Parallel Kernel Status looks like this:

[image]

Is there any way to visualize the kernels without using the built in tool?

Comment: I have never seen so little information from `Parallel Kernel Status`.  Possibly, the CPUs are so busy that they do not find time to provide more info.

Comment: You might mention your version number and operating system